# SQL Server how to sum data of each row

Tags: sql-server, database, division, select-query

So I have two queries that look like this:

```
Query1

CPT       Resource    1       2        3       4      5
2017-06-11  RM1     0.000   28.000  28.000  28.000  28.000
2017-06-11  RM2     14.000  23.000  28.000  28.000  0.000
2017-06-11  RM3     0.000   0.000   27.000  27.000  0.000
2017-06-12  RM1     12.000  34.000  0.000   0.000   28.000
2017-06-12  RM2     0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   28.000
2017-06-12  RM3     17.000  0.000   12.000  0.000   0.000

Query 2
CPT       Resource    1       2        3       4      5
2017-06-11  RM1    -23.000  34.000  -22.000 -28.000  7.000
2017-06-11  RM2    24.000  -15.000   30.000 -18.000 -19.000
2017-06-11  RM3     0.000   0.000   -27.000  27.000  0.000
2017-06-12  RM1     12.000  34.000    0.000  13.000  28.000
2017-06-12  RM2     0.000   0.000   -24.000   0.000  28.000
2017-06-12  RM3   -27.000   16.000   19.000 -18.000  -21.000
```

How do I code a new select query that will return the date, resource, and the total for each row in the first query. Also, I would like it to return the total for each row in the second query as well but I only want it to add up numbers that are negative and then display them as a positive number (multiply the total by -1 or use abs). After this how would you code so that the total for each dated resource in the first query is divided by the matching total for the same in the second query. For example, dividing the total for RM1 on 2017-06-11 in the first query by the total for the same resource and date in the second query and doing this for every row. And how do I make it so that the new column in the new query displaying the divided totals is called "Daily Cost"

Here is an example of what it would look like if I did it manually for the first two rows:

```
Query 3
CPT     Resource        Daily Cost 
2017-06-11  RM1            1.53
2017-06-11  RM2            1.78
```

The math in the first row is done by adding 28+28+28+28=112 for the first row in the first query. Then in the second the query the first row is added (-23)+(-22)+(-28)=-73 and then taking the abs value to get 73. Then 112/73 to get 1.53 as the value for the first row in the third query. How do I code this so that sql does it for me for every row?

Comment: I have read this several times and I just don't get it. What is the "total"? Is that the sum of the numbered columns? I don't at all understand the whole divide part either. Perhaps you need to provide desired output for this sample data and the business rule you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: sorry I will clarify. In the first query each numbered column in both tables is the hour of the day. My original tables number up to 24, but for the sake of saving space I only displayed 5 here. So, for the first table I want to add up every number for each row so that there is a total for each row/date. I want to do the same in the second query however only add the negative numbers. Then I would like to take the total for row 1 in the first query and divide it by the total for row 1 in the second query to get a single number. i would like to do this for each row.

Comment: i am trying to make a third query that displays, CPT, Resource, and the new column of data called Daily Cost

Comment: How about some sample data that we can work with? Or at least the two queries that generate the output above. This sounds like really basic math with a case expression for the second part.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I have updated my post to show what the output I want to look like is and how the math is done

Comment: I assume you want some help with the query. The right way to do this is when you query the data, not later. The math part of this is trivial once we understand how to retrieve the data. All you have shown is a couple of datasets. Help me to help you by providing me some information.

Comment: I would show the actual code for each query but they're super long I feel like that wouldn't help

Answer (score 1):

Not a lot of detail to work with here so I am just converting your sample data to a couple of ctes. The real issue here is that your table is not normalized which makes for very lengthy and ugly queries to do this sort of thing.

```
with Query1 (CPT, Resource, Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4, Value5)as
(
    select '2017-06-11', 'RM1', 0.000, 28.000, 28.000, 28.000, 28.000 union all
    select '2017-06-11', 'RM2', 14.000, 23.000, 28.000, 28.000, 0.000 union all
    select '2017-06-11', 'RM3', 0.000, 0.000, 27.000, 27.000, 0.000 union all
    select '2017-06-12', 'RM1', 12.000, 34.000, 0.000, 0.000, 28.000 union all
    select '2017-06-12', 'RM2', 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 28.000 union all
    select '2017-06-12', 'RM3', 17.000, 0.000, 12.000, 0.000, 0.000
)
, Query2 (CPT, Resource, Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4, Value5)as
(
    select '2017-06-11', 'RM1', -23.000, 34.000, -22.000, -28.000, 7.000 union all
    select '2017-06-11', 'RM2', 24.000, -15.000, 30.000, -18.000, -19.000 union all
    select '2017-06-11', 'RM3', 0.000, 0.000, -27.000, 27.000, 0.000 union all
    select '2017-06-12', 'RM1', 12.000, 34.000, 0.000, 13.000, 28.000 union all
    select '2017-06-12', 'RM2', 0.000, 0.000, -24.000, 0.000, 28.000 union all
    select '2017-06-12', 'RM3', -27.000, 16.000, 19.000, -18.000, -21.000
)
select q1.CPT
    , q1.Resource
    , (q1.Value1 + q1.Value2 + q1.Value3 + q1.Value4 + q1.Value5) 
    / nullif((case when q2.Value1 < 0 then ABS(q2.Value1) else 0 end 
        + case when q2.Value2 < 0 then ABS(q2.Value2) else 0 end 
        + case when q2.Value3 < 0 then ABS(q2.Value3) else 0 end
        + case when q2.Value4 < 0 then ABS(q2.Value4) else 0 end
        + case when q2.Value5 < 0 then ABS(q2.Value5) else 0 end), 0)
from Query1 q1
join Query2 q2 on q1.Resource = q2.Resource 
            and q1.CPT = q2.CPT
```

Comment: this makes sense but how would I do this if there are more than 100 dates for each query. I only posted 2 dates to save time and space

Comment: This is exactly why I was trying to get you to post some details earlier. You wouldn't hard code these ctes like this. You would incorporate the logic in the final query in whatever query it is that gets the data you posted.